# Glue Records For Domain but use different name servers for same domain

Tags: domain-name-system, glue-record

Is it possible to do this:

ns1.domain.com GLUE -> IP

ns2.domain.com GLUE -> IP

BUT for that domain have the name servers point to different provider such as cloudflare?

I want to have glue records for name servers that run on the IP of record but use cloudflare for DNS for that domain.

I need glue records so my customers can use ns1/ns2.domain.com for THEIR name servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glue only can be add via the console of the registrar for root domain.

The concept of glue record is giving A to nameserver.

For example, you can add subdomain on your Cloudflare zone with name sub.domain.com and give A to ns1 & ns2 like :

```
your-dns-ip A ns1.sub.domain.com
your-dns-ip A ns2.sub.domain.com
```

Then giving NS record for sub to ns1 and ns2 like

```
sub.domain.com NS ns1.sub.domain.com
sub.domain.com NS ns2.sub.domain.com
```

After the propagate, you can manage the record for *.sub.domain.com on your DNS Server side.

Hope this will help